# My joomla 3.x website went down and I can't re-run it

Tags: joomla-3.x, server

Hello I have joomla website running lastest vesion 3.3.6 I think. But today suddenly while posting new articles the website got offline. When I try to open the website only blank page is shown, the same is when I try to open /administrator section.

My website is: [Radio Pendimi](http://radio-pendimi.com/website)

After some time the **Page is not avalaible** message is shown

Comment: Based on Lodder's troubleshooting, did you update your DNS A Record to the new servers IP?  Reason being is it appears that the domain name resolution failed, as in the IP provided by the DNS servers was for an IP that has no web server on it.  To verify, ping a domain name you know if functioning on the new server and compare that to the IP when you ping the Radio Pendimi domain.

Comment: The DNS records the nameservers earlier was in CDN service cloudflare but now they are at the main server. The other files and directories hosted at the same server are accesible also the server is online at all time but the joomla website is down/ its not accessible

Comment: How do you mean the files are accessible?  As in a directory listing via the browser?  Can you provide an example link to assist with troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

Just performed a test on here:

http://www.isitdownrightnow.com

and is appears your website is completely down/the server isn't responding. Perhaps you hosting has come to an end due to not being paid or for another reason.

Or it could possibly be that your hosting providers is having issues with their server.

Either way, please contact your hosting provider.

Comment: No it is paid no worry :P ... we transfered our site to a new server and other directories hosted under this server works fine and the server load is minimum but whatever happened for the moment unknown the joomla website didnt work today all day long

Answer (score 0):

There *is no* Joomla site at that URL, it isn't that it has gone offline, there's no Joomla installation there.

You can see this because even the simplest text file, at the root of all Joomla installs, isn't there:

http://radio-pendimi.com/website/robots.txt

Comment: The post is more than 2 months old, and it looks like OP decided to go with WordPress instead of Joomla...

Comment: @johanpw Maybe, but there was no WP site at the URL provided by the OP, so it isn't safe to assume that. True, I didn't notice the post date, mea culpa.

Comment: I've failed to solve this out so I decided to go for wordpress. Now with the wordpress I have more visitors than when I was using joomla and its working great.!